# Kohana 3.3 Validation during update

Tags: php, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3.3 and would like to validate user input in my Controller but it returns the following error:

**ErrorException [ Warning ]: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method**

Here's my Controller:

```
$this->template->user =Auth::instance()->get_user();

                $courseModel = Model::factory('courses');

                $object = Validation::factory($this->request->post());
                // $object->bind(':model', $courseModel);
                $object
                    ->rule('code', 'not_empty')
                    ->rule('code', 'Model_Courses::unique_code')
                    ->rule('code', array('max_length', array(':value', 32)))
                    ->rule('description', 'not_empty');

                if($object->check()) { //this is where the error triggers
                    $user = ORM::factory('courses', $this->request->param('id'))
                        ->values($_POST, array(
                            'code', 
                            'description', 
                        ));

                    $query = DB::update('courses')
                        ->set(array(
                            'code' => $_POST['code'], 
                            'description' => $_POST['description'],
                            ))
                        ->where('id', '=', $this->request->param('id'));

                    $result = $query->execute();

                    // Reset values so form is not sticky
                    $_POST = array();

                    $courses = ORM::factory('courses')
                        ->find_all();
                    $json = array();

                    foreach ($courses as $course) {
                        if($course->id != 1) $json[] = $course->as_array();
                    }
                    $data = json_encode($json);

                    // Display users table
                    $courseView = View::factory('courses/list');
                    $courseView->bind('content', $data);

                    $this->template->content = $courseView;
```

My Model_Courses code is the following:

```
class Model_Courses extends ORM {
protected $_table_name = 'courses';
protected $_primary_key = 'id';

public function rules() {
    return array(
        'code' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
            array(array($this, 'unique'), array(':field', ':value')),
        ),
        'description' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
        ),
    );
}

public static function unique_code($code)
{
    return ! DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(code)'), 'total'))
        ->from('courses')
        ->where('code', '=', $code)
        ->execute()
        ->get('total');
}
```

}

What am I missing? I followed the documentation here:

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The error already gives you the solution.

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method

- [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) is a function that calls a user function (who thought). The only time this happens in your code is in the rules,

  `array(array($this, 'unique'), array(':field', ':value')),`

  Here you want to call a user function via name as string.
- Now it says the first parameter is expected to be a valid callback. The keyword *exptected* tells you, that in your code this is not the case.
- And for the last part, *is not a valid method* is exactly what is causing the problem.

Your methods header is

```
public static function unique_code($code)
```

So the name is not `unique` but `unique_code`

```
array(array($this, 'unique'), array(':field', ':value')), // fails
array(array($this, 'unique_code'), array(':field', ':value')), // should work
```